# An inequality involving norms.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, inequality, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

I have to know how we can show the following inequality:

$\|u\|_{2}\leq\|u_{0}\|_{2}+\int_{0}^{t}\|u_{t}(t,x)\|_{2}dt$

where

$\|u\|_{2}=\Big(\int_{\Omega}u^{2}dx\Big)^{1/2}$, $u_{0}=u(x,0)$, $u_{t}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, $\Omega$  is an open bounded domain in $R^{n}$ and $u=u(x,t)$.

Comment: What is $u_t$? What space does $u$ belongs? Have you tried something?

Comment: Notation is inconsistent. Especially the $\|\cdot\|_2$ seems to have two different meanings (which would be ok if defined properly). Also, what should $u_t(s)$ be?

Comment: Dear friends, please note that I have revised the problem according your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $u \in H^1(0, T; L^2(\Omega))$, you have
$$u(T) = u(0) + \int_0^T u_t(t) \, dt.$$
By the triangle inequality, we find
$$\| u(T) \|_{L^2(\Omega)} \le
\| u(0)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
+
\left\| \int_0^T u_t(t) \, dt\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
\le
\| u(0)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
+
\int_0^T \| u_t(t) \|_{L^2(\Omega)} \, dt.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how did you write the last inequality?

Comment: This follows from simple properties of the Bochner integral, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral.